# Update Xcode 10.1 to 10.2 on High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: xcode, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to update Xcode 10.1 to 10.2 on my High Sierra 10.13.6 version.

The App Store window shows the update button, but the problem is after hitting that button, the circle on the upper-left corner is just rotating for hours and nothing else happens!

[image]

Since the difference between the two versions is not that huge, the update naturally must be downloaded and installed after some time, but in effect it's not that way!

How to solve that issue, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The difference between the two versions **is** <strike>not</strike> that huge* for example Swift 5.0 allows to build projects without the embedded Swift Libraries.

Xcode 10.2 doesn't run in High Sierra. It requires macOS 10.14.3

Comment: So have I to upgrade to Mojave from High Sierra?

Comment: Indeed you've got to

Comment: Another question is, which do you recommend please, migrating from High Sierra to Majave (I'm not sure if it's properly feasible) or uninstalling High sierra and then a clean installation of Mojave?

Comment: It's a matter of taste. Personally I do a clean install on every third major update. For the Mojave update I just ran the installer.

Comment: I have found this link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209606

With this comment: "Xcode 10.2 Released March 25, 2019 Kernel Available for: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 or later".  What does it mean ?

Comment: @PabloAlfonso I regard this as a typo. Xcode 10.2 doesn't launch on 10.13.x

Comment: @vadian  Thanks. Can you please check this answer too from MAhipal Singh ? 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596733/is-it-possible-to-install-xcode-10-2-on-high-sierra-10-13-6

Comment: @pablo-alfonso yeah this is a problem for me because I have 10.2.1 installed on High Sierra just like it says (came down from the AppStore). 10.2.2 is out and now it won't install that update. No idea if I am supposed to downgrade or what. My machine does not support Mojave.

Comment: I migrated from Sierra to Mojave 10.14.2 but Xcode 10.2 needs at least 10.14.3. I tried to update Mojave though App Store, I can't sign in to it although I can sign in to iTunes! Hence, I can't update Mojave and have Xcode 12.2. Is there any direct link of downloading Mojave 10.14.4 to download it without App Store? Or any other way to fix the issue and install Xcode 12.2?

Comment: @Victoria-French I was able to run my app in iOS 12.2 using xCode 10.1 following instructions from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596733/is-it-possible-to-install-xcode-10-2-on-high-sierra-10-13-6.

Comment: It's possible to run Xcode 10.2 on High Sierra, see my answer below

Comment: @Damnum Yes, but there is a good reason why Apple restricted the system version to 10.14 by default. On macOS you are not able to run and test the Mojave API on your High Sierra machine.

Comment: One reason is for them to sell more new hardware I suspect

Comment: @Damnum I disagree. I'm running Mojave on a 9-year old MacPro. In the last 20 years you never could run the latest OS on a 9-year old machine.

Comment: @vadian that's interesting. Are you using a third party patcher tool? As anything before 2012 is not officially supported, no?

Comment: @Damnum I replaced the graphics card with a Metal compatible one as described [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208898)

Comment: Hm they don't mention 2011 models though. Out of interest, can I ask you which graphics card you picked?

Comment: @Damnum A Radeon RX 580

Answer (score 26):

I am using Xcode10.2 on High Sierra 10.13.6, and can build several projects for my iPhone 5s and 6s Plus which working on iOS12.2. The process is similar to Damnum’s.

1. Change the name of working Xcode like Xcode10.1.
2. Download Xcode 10.2 and copy it into Applications folder. (The name is of course Xcode.)
3. Edit Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist and change the Minimum System Version to 10.13.6 with Xcode10.1
4. Edit Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge/Contents/Info.plist and change the Minimum System Version to 10.13.6 with Xcode10.1
5. Edit Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/Info.plist and change the Minimum System Version to 10.13 with Xcode10.1
6. Launch Xcode (it is 10.2) and install the rest of items.
7. Now you can use iOS12.2 features in the Xcode.

I tested my own projects and several sample projects from iOS 12 App Development Essentials by Neil Smyth. All of them work fine on my devises including camera app.

Comment: This process also works well for Xcode 10.2.1. If you are using Xcode 10.2 on High Sierra, change 10.1 above to 10.2 and 10.2 to 10.2.1.

Comment: I was able to update Xcode like this, but I have problem with git. When I try to use git status I get this error: Executable requires at least macOS 10.14, but is being run on macOS 10.13.6, and so is exiting.git: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly! Does someone know a solution for this?

Comment: Ok, I just got it working like this: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-10-1.app/Contents/Developer Basically I changed the developer tools to be used from the old Xcode

Comment: What's the meaning of "... with Xcode10.1" in Step 3, 4 & 5? I believe we are editing files within 10.2 (or 10.2.1), not 10.1?!

Comment: @charleslcso , in 10.12.1, the Info.plist is binary file, I have to use `plutil -convert xml1 Info.plist` before edit it using Sublime text3. I guess, using xcode editor can directly edit the Info.plist file.

Comment: @stellz I'm having the same error "Executable requires at least macOS 10.14" and I tried what you said, did you have to do anything else because my projects won't build :(

Comment: @AndrewFashion I had the same issue, and solved it by restarting the computer.

Comment: I was able to run Xcode and the Simulators with this, but if I tried building a Xcode project to run on a device, I would run into an error. I found on https://codewithchris.com/xcode-update/ that if I copied the from Xcode 10.1 the Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild to the Xcode 10.2's location, I was able to build and run on a device again. (And also @Dumnum's answer mentions that step too)

Comment: The same process can be applied with Xcode 10.3 on High Sierra 10.13.6. It can build iOS 12.4 applications.

Comment: @Tripod, for further clarification when you reference "change the Minimum System Version to 10.13.6 with Xcode10.1" do you mean to literally change in the new /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist -><key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
 <string>10.2</string>
to 10.1?

Comment: 'change the Minimum System Version to 10.13 with Xcode10.1' = Using Xcode 10.1, change the  Minimum System Version (from 10.4) to 10.13.

Answer (score 8):

Follow these steps:

1. Download Xcode 10.2 via this link (you need to be signed in with your Apple Id): https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.2/Xcode_10.2.xip and install it
2. Edit Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist and change the Minimum System Version to 10.13.6
3. Do the same for Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/Info.plist (might require a restart of Xcode and/or Mac OS to make it open the simulator on run)
4. Replace Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild with one from 10.1

Comment: Thanks so much, +1. I upgraded to Mojave 10.14.4, and installed Xcode there but my App Store doesn't work there!

Comment: That's not enough, Xcode Info.plist's have also other parameters as "BuildMachineOSBuild" that refeers to 10.14.3. Indeed Xcode still don't start with your instructions.. Unknown class GPUTesselationSliderCell in Interface Builder file...it search for Mojave private API methods..

Comment: I'm trying to install Xcode for the first time in my Imac stuck in the 10.13.6 version then I don't have previous installations from where I can get the xcodebuild file. Any idea from where can I get the file?

Comment: Save yourself an hour of debugging and follow the steps in the accepted answer by @tripod instead. It changes the versions in more places, which are necessary

Answer (score 0):

As it doesn't appear to have been mentioned in the existing answers/comments, for completeness, the last version of Xcode to run on High Sierra (macOS 10.13.2) is version 9.4.1, but on macOS 10.13.6 the last supported version of Xcode is version 10.1

---

From [Xcode want install on high Sierra 10.13.6](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128517):

> [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode%C2%A0has) a good summary of compatibility versions. Looks like for 10.13.6 you'll need Xcode 9.4.1

Looking on https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

- [Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.1.dmg](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.1.dmg)
- [Xcode_9.4.1.xip](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.4.1/Xcode_9.4.1.xip)

However, once 9.4.1 is installed upon 10.13.6, then there is an update offered for the CLT on the AppStore to version 10.1,

[image: CLT for Xcode 10.1 update]

When the [Xcode 7.0 - 10.x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_7.0_-_10.x_(since_Free_On-Device_Development)) section of the Wikipedia page is checked, it can be seen that the quote above is not (entirely) correct, depending upon which version of High Sierra you have installed:

- For 10.13.2, Xcode 9.4.1 is the last supported version

  - [Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.1.dmg](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.1.dmg)
  - [Xcode_9.4.1.xip](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.4.1/Xcode_9.4.1.xip)
- For 10.13.6, Xcode 10.1 is the last supported version

  - [Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10.1.dmg](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10.1.dmg)
  - [Xcode_10.1.xip](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.1/Xcode_10.1.xip)

[image: Xcode 7.0 - 10.x compatibility]