# Is it possible to install Xcode 10.2 on High Sierra (10.13.6)?

Tags: macos-high-sierra, xcode10.2

I recently upgraded iOS in my iPhone device to 12.2 (to provide support of latest versions for my app "Match4app"), and this does not appear to be compatible with Xcode 10.1. Should I update Xcode to 10.2 ?

In my Mac with High Sierra, when I click "Update" for Xcode, 10.2 is not available.

I have found this link:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209606

With this comment:
**"Xcode 10.2
Released March 25, 2019
Kernel
Available for: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 or later"**

How can I install Xcode 10.2 with High Sierra in order to test iOS 12.2 ?

Note: Upgrading to Mojave or Catalina is NOT an option in my old Mac (though I will try to install the macOS Catalina Patcher soon (http://dosdude1.com/catalina/) ).

Comment: The Info.plist file inside Xcode 10.2 specifies a minimum system version of 10.14.3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Xcode 10.1 to 10.2 on High Sierra 10.13.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55578496/update-xcode-10-1-to-10-2-on-high-sierra-10-13-6)

Answer (score 48):

Yes it's possible. Follow these steps:

1. Download Xcode 10.2 via this link (you need to be signed in with your Apple Id): https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.2/Xcode_10.2.xip and install it
2. Edit Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist and change the Minimum System Version to 10.13.6
3. Do the same for Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/Info.plist (might require a restart of Xcode and/or Mac OS to make it open the simulator on run)
4. Replace Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild with the one from 10.1 (or another version you have currently installed, such as 10.0).
5. If there are problems with the simulator, reboot your Mac

Comment: I've tries all steps, and still not working. It complais about mac os version, "application require macOS 10.14.3". Any ideas?

Comment: This worked for me, but now GitHub account for source control is unavailable. Is there any workaround?

Comment: you could rename the 10.2 version to "Xcode102" to check before replacing the previous version, too. Xcode can have several xcode versions parallel in your applications folder

Comment: @masoud I had a similar issue once where git failed to work after Xcode was updated.  My solution was to download git again from https://git-scm.com/downloads and install it.  Then, I had to update the `PATH` in my `~/.profile` file so that `/usr/local/bin` took precedence over `/usr/bin`

Comment: Note, if the plist files above are in binary format, then use this information to change them to editable text: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5278/how-do-i-edit-a-plist-file

Comment: Worked for me as a separate xcode_102 app, with the above mentioned info.plist changes. Or you could rename the old to xcode_101 and have the latest as xcode. A reboot will also fix the simulator issues which seems to be a mac issue (see #26846139).

Comment: "Replace Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild with the one from 10.2" This does not make sense to me - he is installing 10.2, did you mean 10.1 maybe? Or do you mean replacing 10.2 to the old 10.1?

Comment: I went through manually (hopefully) all *.plist files through the subdirectories and found one extra mentioning 10.14.3 as minimum system version:

Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app/Contents/Info.plist

Comment: XCode10.3 seems to work with this guide as well as long as XCode 10.3 is renamed to Xcode in /Applications and then run once. Also a reboot was needed after running XCode the first time.

Comment: Does anybody know if this method works with Xcode 11 on High Sierra as well?

Comment: This did not work for me on MacOS 12..7.1 trying to get Xcode 14.3.1 to work.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for installing Xcode 15.2 on macOS Monterey 12.7.3.

Answer (score 18):

You don't need to run Xcode 10.2 for iOS 12.2 support. You just need access to the appropriate folder in DeviceSupport.

A possible solution is

- Download Xcode 10.2 from a direkt link (not from App Store).
- Rename it for example to Xcode102.
- Put it into `/Applications`. It's possible to have multiple Xcode versions in the same directory.
- Create a symbolic link in Terminal.app to have access to the 12.2 device support folder in Xcode 10.2

  ```
  ln -s /Applications/Xcode102.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/12.2\ \(16E226\) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
  ```

You can move Xcode 10.2 to somewhere else but then you have to adjust the path.

Now Xcode 10.1 supports devices running iOS 12.2

Comment: Thanks. I will try it tonight. Can I just copy/paste the DeviceSupport/12.2 directory into "Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport" instead of uncompressing the whole packet ?

Comment: This could be possible, too.

Comment: Downloaded 6GB of data just to get this directory (13 MB) but this works :)

Comment: its just for support ios 12 but wont compile swift 5.0 .

Comment: Does this approach work with Xcode 10.3 too? For getting iOS 12.4.1 device support on High Sierra?

Comment: @JasperHBojsen Honestly I don't know. Try it, you cannot ruin anything. If it doesn't work delete the symbolic link

Comment: I will try. I support the source path: `...DeviceSupport/12.2\ \(16E226\) ...` should be changed to: `...DeviceSupport/12.4\ \(16E226\) ...` then?

Answer (score 16):

Download xcode 10.2 from below link
https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.2/Xcode_10.2.xip

**Edit: Minimum System Version*** to **10.13.6** in **Info.plist** at below paths

1. `Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist`
2. `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/Info.plist`

**Replace:** `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild` from **Xcode 10**

****OR*****

you can install disk image of 12.2 in your existing xcode to run on 12.2 devices
Download disk image from here
https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/releases/download/12.2/12.2.16E5191d.zip

And paste at Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

Note: Restart the Xcode

Comment: Mahipal, according to this comment from @vadian, installing 10.2 on High Sierra is not possible. Did you try this solution already ?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55578496/update-xcode-10-1-to-10-2-on-high-sierra-10-13-6

Comment: Pablo Alfonso, I have share you two steps either download from link (not to update)or add disk image in exiting xcode folder... it will works ...We normally do step 2(adding disk image) instead of updating or downloading new xcode for minor versions of iOS  and Vadian is also saying samething.

Comment: Thx, its in the right folder, but doe not appear in the deployment target in Xcode10.1. Deleting the weird extension of the 12.2 Folder an idea?

Comment: "Replace: Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild from Xcode 10" I do not understand. Did you mean "from Xcode 10.1"?

Comment: @Kozuch sorry for late reply, yes *Xcode.app* --> your xcode in (Application Folder) i.e Xcode 10.1

Comment: I'm trying to install Xcode for the first time in my Imac stuck in the 10.13.6 version then I don't have previous installations from where I can get the xcodebuild file. Any idea from where can I get the file?

Comment: @HMario after extraction of .xip file , check you Xcode.app with ban icon , just right click on it and follow the steps.

Comment: Sorry @MAhipalSingh but I don't understand. I'm already extracted, installed and follow the steps 1 and 2 editing the Info.plist files, but I can't replace the file "Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild" because I don't have previous installations from where a can get it. I'm asking where I can grab the file. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: This method doesn't work for Xcode 10.3. Is there any other steps to make the newer version compatible with high sire?

Comment: Hi @HMarioD can you please share with me how did you able to resolve this issue ran into the same problem
Thanks.

Comment: @aashirkhan I couldn't solve it until now. For now, I'm programming on a 13-inch Macbook. I'm still waiting for an answer here. If you can solve it please let me know.

Comment: @HMarioD I found the only solution is to upgrade my OS to macOS Mojave then I able to install Xcode 10.

Comment: @aashirkhan I can't do the upgrade to Mohave because I have a 2011 IMac. Thanks anyway for the hint : )

Comment: This did not work for me on MacOS 12..7.1 trying to get Xcode 14.3.1 to work.

Answer (score 9):

Based on responses and comments below, the following was the simple solution for my issue and THIS WORKED. Now my app, Match4app, is fully compatible with latest iOS versions!

1. Download Xcode 10.2 from a direct link (not from App Store). (Estimated Size: ~6Gb)
2. From the downloaded version just copy/paste the DeviceSupport/12.2 directory into "Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport"
3. You can discard the downloaded version now (we just need the small 12.2 directory!)

Comment: Alternatively you can download them from https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport (credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55975906/1259478)

Answer (score 3):

None of the above helped for me.

I was able to install Mojave using this link here: 
http://dosdude1.com/mojave/
This patch worked beautifully and without a hitch

Proof: 
[here's Mojave running on my (unsupported) 2011 Mac-mini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS8I3.png)

Comment: Be careful with this, if you have an iMac with a ATI Radeon HD 5xxx or 6xxx majave will not run properly. Bit of a shame as I had a fully maxed out 2010 iMac with SSD etc that still runs like a dream today. But because of this I can't use Xamarin/xcode. Going to have to take the plunge and get a new mac. Lesson learned though is don't max out your mac, since apple will put a time limit on its use anyway grrrr.

Comment: Thats ridiculous, they can't just get ATI to make the drivers? i'm in the same boat here with the 27" 2011 version.

Comment: Same thing here. Apple and their programmed obsolescence. @Blingers, one option is to build your apps remotely using a CI/CD pipeline. Do not know if this would help your case.

Answer (score -2):

Cracked it. Just @Damnum steps and then follow the path to run xcode. Bad way but running like a charm.

Double click to /Applications/Xcode102.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Comment: How do you double click to that folder?  I'm kind of new to Mac, just using this one to upload my app to the appstore.

Comment: /Applications/Xcode102.app .. right click to that app and click on "show package content" then follow the path then press twice left click on that xcode