# This iPhone 6 is running iOS 12.3.1 (16F203), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, sdk, xcode10.1

Xcode updated to the latest version 10.2 recently and so did the iOS to 12.3.1. My Mac is an older mac that's working on High Sierra and I cannot update to Mojave. I have Xcode 10.1. How do I add the supporting files and where can I find them? Any help would be appriciated. Thank you

I have tried copying the files from a folder with 12.2 and restarting Xcode but to no luck

Comment: Did not find a workaround.  My mac is now a dawg creeping under the mojave POS, as are my test devices. Way to go apple, planned obsolescence is now multi-platform.

Comment: I totally get you @YvesLeBorg... I posted an answer below, I use an old 2009 unibody white mac, Not giving up yet :)

Comment: also, just for kicks : I use eXcode to play certificates, for everything else there is AppCode (Jetbrains)

Comment: I was recommended AppCode too, I was wondering if its Storyboard feature would be good as I'm a noob and rely a lot on Storyboards. Can you also run the code on a device with AppCode @YvesLeBorg. Thanks for the response bud

Comment: No, AppCode does not. However, you can open your projects/workspaces with both without fail (so you could use eXcode to do that too ... but it sucks hard imnsho, compared to say ... Android Studio, also a Jetbrains product). I find it much easier to layout by code strictly. I got truckloads of reusable code/patterns by now.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg: just wanted to say thank you for the input and direction. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 23):

So after many findings and following links, I have found a solution for anyone struggling out there. Steps as follows

1. Shut down Xcode.. I mean to quit it
2. Go to this link and download this [file](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/12.2%20(16E226).zip)
3. create a folder named 12.3 (16F203) and copy the extracted two files... take note, this includes a "DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature" and "DeveloperDiskImage.dmg" (I found that these files eventually work fine as opposed to copying other files from previous folders... might be the dmg files)
4. run the following command on your terminal window... please note, adjust the file path according to your installation of Xcode. "ln -s /Users/damn_son/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/12.3\ (16F203) /Users/damn_son/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ \DeviceSupport\"
5. I found that step number 4 links the file as mentioned in this [thread](https://gist.github.com/steipete/d9b44d8e9f341e81414e86d7ff8fb62d). it did the trick
6. re-start Xcode and try compiling and running again. good luck

Comment: Instead of creating a link, you might just copy the directory into "Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport" as described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596733/is-it-possible-to-install-xcode-10-2-on-high-sierra-10-13-6

Comment: Thank you so much captain_haddock. You saved my day. It works. But pls change your command it's showing error. I have changed little bit and it works.

Comment: @KarnanMuthukumar: I purposely added the words"damn_son" to mask my real hard disk name as its my name :)... so where it says "damn_son" insert your home drive name. thank you for the comliment

Comment: command gives error even after changing to real hard disk name, error is `syntax error near unexpected token '(' `

Answer (score 12):

FolderName  is important, check spacing also

1.create file with name 12.3.1 (16F203)

2.copy the contents(from https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/12.2%20(16E226).zip)

3.paste the folder in the DeviceSupport folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/ and copy-paste the contents.

4.quit the xcode and relaunch.

Comment: Inside applications Xcode.app is not found in my mac

Comment: @yaswanthkoneri  goto Xcode documents folder right click on Xcode and and click on "Show package content" then go to the path as per step number 3.

Comment: You save my day. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download Xcode 10.2 from a direct link (not from App Store). (Estimated Size: ~6Gb):
   https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.2/Xcode_10.2.xip
2. From the downloaded version just copy/paste the content of directory DeviceSupport/12.2 directory into "Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/12.3 (16F203)"
3. You can discard the downloaded version now (we just need the small 12.2 directory!)

Comment: Worked perfect for me! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

1.create file with name **12.3.1** (16F203)

2.copy the contents(from https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/12.2%20(16E226).zip)

3.paste the folder in the DeviceSupport folder `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/` and copy-paste the contents.

4.quit the Xcode and relaunch.

to goto, Xcode documents folder right click on Xcode and click on "Show package content"
then go to the path as per step number 3.