# Is it possible to install Xcode 11 on High Sierra (10.13.6)?

Tags: macos-high-sierra, xcode11

I have a Mac early 2011 running MacOS high sierra 10.13.6.
My Mac can't upgrade to higher MacOS versions.

I need to install XCode 11 to take advantage of SwiftUI.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596733/is-it-possible-to-install-xcode-10-2-on-high-sierra-10-13-6?newreg=2b46ba4ca26b44228f3c52b78165554f) worked for XCode 10.2 but didn't work for XCode 11.

So can I install XCode11 on MacOS high sierra 10.13.6?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596733/is-it-possible-to-install-xcode-10-2-on-high-sierra-10-13-6?noredirect=1&lq=1 I havn't downloaded any of the newer stuff to try myself, but like yourself I want to install xcode11 on high sierra.

Comment: On the internet there are some workarounds to install Mojave on an older unsupported Mac so you can try to go that way. First try to install Mojave with some workaround and if that will work then after that you should be able to install Xcode 11.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but if you just want to have he sdk you can copy it over to the older xcode. This doesn't guarantee that any new ios 13 features will work, but if it's just a matter of wanting to run the simulator and testing on a physical device that has ios 13, it's working for me. Again, I'm not using any new features for ios 13. So in the case that you do want to do that you'll have to get a new mac. Let me know if you need the details on what folders to copy over (I did a backup of the old ones in case something ever comes up).

Comment: Anyone able to sort out this issue? please do let me know coz I also have same issue...

Comment: @pqsk with my last uploaded archive to Appstoreconnect I have isuue "WARNING ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 12.1 SDK. Starting April 30, 2020, new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later, included in Xcode 11 or later." I have iMac mid 2010 with iOS 10.13.6, Xcode 10.1. I don't ude any new iOS 13 feutures I need only iOS 13 SDKs, can you tel me how to copy to my old Xcode10.1?

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55645290/9161478

Comment: I was able to get it to work, but only for iOS. I've been trying for 2 days now to get it to work on watchOS. compilation fails for that one. something is missing in the sdk that is buried somewhere in xcode perhaps. but maybe with swift it would work. I'm using all objective-c. the bad thing is for swift you probably have to manually migrate that (reason why I stopped using swift). Anyways I was able to update one of my apps and publish to the store using XCode 10.2.1 (using instructions from: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55596733/545657, but you could easily use xcode 10.1 too).

Comment: scratch the swift part. watchos doesn't work for swift either. well if you compile for the simulator there are no issues, but then you can't publish to the app store. The good thing also is that the ios 13 framework additions work too. Although I'm not sure if the storyboard will work properly with the latest changes. I did experience in 1 project I downloaded from github I had to manually change the xml and remove a constraint in the xml and then it compiled without issues.

Comment: downgrading the watchOS sdk appears to be the only solution right now. I just submitted a app for review and it was accepted. So that's proof that the old xcode can be used, which is good news for those of us with an older macbook

Answer (score 3):

From Xcode 11 [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_release_notes):

> Xcode 11 requires a Mac running macOS 10.14.3 or later.

So you cannot install Xcode 11 on macOS 10.13.6

Comment: @MostafaMazrouh: There is none. You cannot magically make an app that requires a minimum version of macOS _X_ run on macOS < _X_ . Well, you can manipulate the `Info.plist` file to allow it launch but it's very likely to crash because it may link frameworks which do not exist on your system or call symbols which do not exist.

Comment: previously there was some workarounds which was provide ability to install Xcode on old Mac OS versions. also I don't see any significant changes in new Mac OS and Xcode version. I don't see the reasonable reason to raise up min version. so that thing from Release Notes really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade old macbook pro using this patch http://dosdude1.com/mojave/.
You can easily use Xcode 11.

Comment: the question is if it is possible to install Xcode 11 on High Sierra, not if it is possible to upgrade High Sierra.