# How To Run Xcode 11 in Macos High Sierra?

Tags: macos-high-sierra, xcode11

I have a Mac early 2011 running MacOS high sierra 10.13.6. My Mac can't upgrade to higher MacOS versions.

I need to install XCode 11 to take advantage of SwiftUI.

This answer worked for XCode 10.2 but didn't work for XCode 11.

So can I install XCode11 on MacOS high sierra 10.13.6?

Comment: Xcode 11 needs 10.4.4. Time for a new Mac.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to install Xcode 11 on High Sierra (10.13.6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512172/is-it-possible-to-install-xcode-11-on-high-sierra-10-13-6)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade old mac using this patch http://dosdude1.com/mojave/. You can easily use Xcode 11.

Comment: Anybody tested this solution please advice