# How to install Xcode 15.2 on macOS Monterey 12.7.3

Tags: xcode, macos, info.plist, macos-monterey

I've old iMac with Monterey 12.7.3 on it, is it possible to install Xcode 15.2 on this?

I've followed this tutorial [Is it possible to install Xcode 10.2 on High Sierra (10.13.6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596733/is-it-possible-to-install-xcode-10-2-on-high-sierra-10-13-6) to change the info.plist and other changes but it still doesn't work.

It is old iMac so I can't update macOS on it.

Comment: It' sold iMac can't update macOS, stuck with Monterey.

Comment: @matt I think we need a new Apple. Enough junk my 10 year old iMac is perfectly capable but because of Apple's policy I have to spend hours researching and applying hacks to make it do anything useful. If I had followed the official way I'd have gone through 3 computers and stacks of money, how wasteful and polluting.

Comment: @Rolf well said, I also don't want to end up with piles of iMacs and MacBooks just because Apple doesn't support latest versions of some apps on old system. I really don't need to buy one more Mac right now just for Xcode, it's nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how old your computer is, you could update to MacOS 13 with the help of [Open Core Legacy Patcher](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/SONOMA-DROP.html)

Of course running xcode 15 on osx 12 would be a better solution but I'm still looking for the answer.

Comment: Yes, I've already seen Open Core route of fixing it, this is not what I wanted to do. Unfortunately it is not possible.

Comment: @Vaughn opencore worked fine for me. It's amazing what they managed to do. Another suggestion is to use a cloud mac service such as MacIncloud to use Xcode 15

Comment: I don't think anyone who has all his life's stuff on a Mac should use Open Core. Not sure what it will breakup and then you are stuck. If you have spare mac then yes you can try. Renting mac in cloud is fucking stupidity.

Comment: @Vaughn sounds like such a person would need backups

Comment: @Vaughn The reason i want xcode 15 is that when i try to upload new version to testflight i got this error : (ITMS-90725: SDK version issue - This app was built with the iOS 16.2 SDK. Starting April 29, 2024, all iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later, included in Xcode 15 or later, in order to be uploaded to App Store Connect or submitted for distribution.)  i tried mac in cloud as well it's not working for me because i need real device to build the production.