# XCode 14.3 on Monterey 12.5.1

Tags: xcode, simulator, xcode14.3

After updating to XCode 14.3 on an older MP 5,1 running 12.5.1 and modifying the Info.plist for XCode using these guidelines:
[Update Xcode 10.1 to 10.2 on High Sierra 10.13.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55578496/update-xcode-10-1-to-10-2-on-high-sierra-10-13-6) everything is working fine, including building to a real device running 16.4, except that the simulators running 16.4 only show a blank black screen. Simulators running iOS 15 work fine.

I looked at the Info.plist for the Simulator.app as well but it's minimum system version is still at 12.0 so there was no change necessary. I also tried replacing the Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild with the one from 14.2 and there was no change so I put the 14.3 one back in place. I also tried rebooting the system, no change.

Unfortunately, due to the AVX2 instructions required for Ventura, updating an MP 5,1 to Ventura with OpenCore has some serious issues. Monterey is very stable and since I can't update my OS, but needed to update my iPhone's OS, I had to move to 14.3.

While I don't often use Simulators, I do need them to work when I need them. Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Update: I installed the 16.2 Simulator into XCode 14.3 and it works just fine like it used to. Still 16.4 Simulator does not do anything but crash ScreenTimeAgent. Would love a resolution if anyone finds one.

Comment: Thank you for posting what you've done thus far.  I'm moving forward on updating OSX to Monterey and am duplicating your process.  Fingers crossed I can match it successfully!  I tried getting the newer Xcode running with this method on OSX Big Sur 11.x and it did not work.  Neither did adding device support files to older Xcode 13.

Comment: I also want to add that in order for me to get Xcode 14.3 working on Monterey, I had to do some extra steps.  It would open to the startup license screen and pressing agree would not work.  I believe it was still pointed to the older version of developer tools.  I ran the following commands: 

$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-14.3.app/Contents/Developer 

Then

$ sudo xcodebuild -license accept

References: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/26772631/430134

Comment: Edit the XCode 14.3 Info.plist using XCode 14.2 and just change the minimum system version to 12.0. That should be all that is required as long as you are running 12.5.1 (can't speak for later versions as that's the version I'm running). Then in simulator, install the 16.2 simulators and disable all the 16.4 sims from showing up in the list. That should get you going.

Comment: Yup, I did that plus those steps and I am up and running :)

Answer (score 0):

To install Xcode 14.3 or later on Monterey

### download apple Xcode app

You will need to connected to your apple account

[Connexion - Apple](https://developer.apple.com/download/applications/)

Download link:

[Xcode Releases Xcode 14.3 | xcodereleases.com](https://xcodereleases.com/?q=14.3)

### Fix compatibility problems

- You must keep your working xcode version as is it.
- uncompress xcode release xip (double click) inside a tempory directory like */mytempDir* .

Then inside */Applications*:

- ```bash
  sudo mv /mytempDir/Xcode.app Xcode-143.app
  ```
- Edit with visual studio code the file /Applications/Xcode-143.app/Contents/Info.plist with

```bash
cd /Applications/Xcode-143.app/Contents
sudo code Info.plist
```

- You will have a binary file problem, add the *"Blinary PList"* extension, and "Open Anyway" -> Text Editor.
- Modify "LSMinimumSystemVersion" to 12.5
- Do the same for */Applications/Xcode-143.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents*

To change your new Xcode installation as default:

- `sh sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-143.app/Contents/Developer`
- `sh sudo xcodebuild -license accept`

That's all folks!

Comment: Not working, on the last step I get the error: `xcodebuild: error: unable to execute utility "/Applications/Xcode-143.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild" because it requires a newer version of macOS.`. I'm installing XCode 15.3